# Generic Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, events, callback

In Javascript, I see that there is already an `Event` interface and a child called `CustomEvent`. I am wondering if these are good fits for a c# type of `event` / `delegate` system. I want to create a way of subscribing to events, but I was getting stuck on how to unsubscribe gracefully.

```
function MyClass(){
    this.onDoCoolThing = null;
}

MyClass.prototype.doCoolThing = function(){
    // do thing  
    if(this.onDoCoolThing !== null){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.onDoCoolThing.length; i++){
            if(this.onDoCoolThing[i] instanceof Function)
              this.onDoCoolThing[i]();
        }
    }     
}
```

First of, how would I subscribe? These are my ideas:

**C# Method**

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.onDoCoolThing += myCallbackFunction.bind(this, param1);
myClass.onDoCoolThing += myOtherCallbackFunction.bind(this, param1);
```

**Array style**
If the C# method is not possible:

```
myClass.onDoCoolThing.push(myCallBackFunction.bind(this, param1);
```

I don't know how I would unsubscribe from those if lets say, the object with the callback was destroyed. Will it be GCed?

That's why I am wondering if this work has been done and is found in a native object, but I don't really see it anywhere.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're asking.. you just want to bind/unbind a function to events? Or is there more to it than that.

Comment: Start from [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: @acupajoe I'm trying to recreate C# events (Java probably has the same). I want a way to subscribe to an objects events, and unsubscribe as well. I should be able to control when these events are fired (ie within a function scope)

Comment: Thanks @hindmost, I can't get Event to work in its simplest form (I think it must be attached to a DOM object) so I will write my own.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it cleanly in vanilla JS.

However, jQuery provides a delegate method so you can assign handlers after DOM load. Just pull in the jQuery library. You can write a function manually to do it in Vanilla JS, but it is much easier to let jQuery handle it for you.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: "if this work has been done and is found in a **native** object"

Comment: There is no method in vanilla JS that provides for the assignment of delegates. You have to write your own. I am providing a quicker way. A far as I have seen the vanilla way to do it in JS is not well supported cross client.

Comment: I'm aware of that, was just providing a reason for why you're being downvoted. He asked for a native way to implement it. If there's not a native way to do it, it should be specified in the answer before offering an alternative.

Comment: it should be specified in the answer before offering an alternative.

You are correct. My mistake.

Comment: The thing is I'm not interested in anything to do with DOM, this is about application level objects.

Comment: Maybe the "watch" method might be what you are looking for. It is the only way I know of to watch for events on non DOM level objects. It is a decedent of Object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Comment: I see. Well looks like native JS is useless for this, as everything is geared towards DOM elements. I will continue to write my own.